# Can't see EF database in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: entity-framework

I have created a database using EF code-first like there http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx. But when I input data to db by `add()` and then call `savechanges()` I don't see new database in SQL Server databases folder and there no exceptions. Is it right? Where can I find my database and how to put it in databases folder?

I work with this code:

```
     public class Name
      {
       public long NameId { get; set; }
       public string FullName { get; set; }
      }

   public class InfoContext : DbContext
     {
       public DbSet<Name> Names { get; set; }        
     }
```

Then I call it:

```
      var db = new InfoContext();
        var Names = new Name
        {
            NameId = 1,
            FullName = "test"
        };
        db.Names.Add(Name);

        db.SaveChanges();
        var test = db.Names.Find(1);//there I get correct value
```

I have connectionString in web.config like this:

```
     <connectionStrings>
     <add name="InfoName" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     connectionString="Server = .\MYINSTANCE; Initial Catalog=mydbname;" />
   </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're not connecting to the correct SQL server instance. Check your app.config and see what `type` the key `defaultConnectionFactory` has.

Comment: There is no app.config in my project mvc4 as default. How to create and fill it ? When I restart debug mode I get exception that say about existing database and recommend migration.

Comment: If you're getting that error then the DbContext is connection to something. Is there a web.config file?

Comment: I have web.config in main folder with connectionstring and in Views.

Comment: Your DbContext is InfoContext, yet your connectionString name is "InfoName".  They must be the same unless you add a constructor overload to specify the connection string name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments you need to modify the `web.config` file in your project root (not the one in your `Views` folder. In there you can add a section as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source = .; Initial Catalog = ITSDB; Integrated Security = true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The name property of the element is the DbContext name of your Data model, so if your class is defined as:

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
      ...
}
```

Then your config should be:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SomeContext" connectionString="Data Source = .; Initial Catalog = ITSDB; Integrated Security = true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

As for the connection string, its dependent on your database.

Comment: I added my code example. If I use cString name like SomeContext class name an error occurs (incorrect cString).

Answer (score 0):

Check the defaultConnectionFactory type in your config. I expect it is set to LocalConnectionFactory, as this seems to be default.

Change it to the following and your SQL instance will be used.

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="Data Source=.; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

Your DB should appear in SQL Management Studio (SQLMS) with a name that matches the namespace and DbContext.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just put in "Data Source = " value your server's name which selected in you SQL Management Studio.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SomeContext" connectionString="Data Source = **Server'sName**; Initial Catalog = ITSDB; Integrated Security = true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```